# How can I persuade Google Application Engine to cache my static files

Tags: google-cloud-platform, caching

Google Cloud Run is not caching my static files: css and js. I've replaced many of them with CDN equivalent links and those are getting automatically cached, but I have a few still left in static, actually in application/static/horizontal.

You can see the download times in this snapshot.
[image: Timing of cached entries]

In the app.yaml file I have

```
- url: /static
  static_dir: application/static
  expiration: "1d 0h"

- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|bmp|css|otf|eot|svg|ttf|woff))
  static_files: application/static
  upload: application/static/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|bmp|css|otf|eot|svg|ttf|woff))
  expiration: "1d 0h"
```

My reading of the url syntax above is that files in application/static/horizontal/*.css and *.js should be cached. But GCR is ignoring me.... Thrashing around a bit, I did just change app.yaml header to add a cache-control and default expiration, as shown below. But that hasn't helped either.

```
# application:  x
# version: 1
runtime: python39
# api_version: 1
# threadsafe: true
instance_class: F4
default_expiration: "5m"
cache-control: public
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT run:app
```

I've also tried hosting a static files in Cloud Storage database and they also (a) download blindingly fast and (b) get cached without any effort from me. But also (c) it seems not possible to get app.yaml to serve static files from the Cloud Storage so that is not perfect.

I dont think this is a duplicate question - all I can find on Stackexchange is people asking to turn *off* static caches. I have the opposite problem... Suggestions appreciated.

[Edit] I added a snapshot of the response. I see the "1d" aka 86400 seconds, so that part of the YAML is getting through. As to the "no-cache" and "private" that is a mystery.
[image: Header Response]

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up doing. I dont know why the YAML, etc, doesnt create a cache, but the files are served by Flask and I can force the header response as shown below and that [I suppose?] overrides some typo that I made somewhere, and the static files now all cache perfectly. I recognize that this is a bit of a band-aid.

```
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
origin = ["*"]
response.headers.extend([("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", orig) for orig in origin])
response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE')

if "no-cache" in response.cache_control:
   response.cache_control.pop("no-cache")
response.cache_control.public = True
response.cache_control.max_age = 86400 #one day

return response
```